# Sequence of attack in a Turn-Based Game in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I am trying to make a turn-based game in javascript but I am having a lot of troubles to iterate over the units slots of players.

1) A player can have until 8 slots, so I did:

```
this.army = [
            {            
                amount: 2000,
                name:   'monster',           
                atk:    500,
                def:    600,
                spd:    10,
                hp:     500,
            },
            {
                amount: 1500,
                name:  'vampyre',
                atk:   700,
                def:   300,
                spd:   40,
                hp:    650,
            },
            {
                amount: 200,
                name:   'ghost',
                tier:   'frontline',
                atk:    500,
                def:    600,
                spd:    25,
                hp:     500,
            }
        ];
```

2) The enemy have something like that too.
3) I did create a battle queue (based on units spd) using:

```
battleFollowing = function(attacker, defender) {
    var armyList = attacker.army.concat(defender.army);
    var orderedList = armyList.sort( function(a, b) {
                        var a1 = a.spd, b1 = b.spd;
                        if (a1 === b1) return 0;
                        return a1 > b1 ? -1 : 1;
                    });
    return orderedList;
}
```

But this way, the commander army order is not the same than original arrange. How can I to define the original slot index to use the array.splice() function to remove the dead slot?

Sorry my bad english.